# Getting "The connection to 'localhost' failed" error when trying to browse localhost site on IIS

Tags: iis, localhost

My localhost IIS sites recently stopped working and I can't figure out why.  If I try and browse to http://localhost after a while I get the error `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost`.  If I open Fiddler and try again I get a `502` error that states `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 127.0.0.1:80`

- I've tried using `netstat -a -b` to see if any other applications are blocking port 80, but there doesn't appear to be anything obvious.
- I've disabled proxy servers and that doesn't have any affect.
- As a last resort I even tried re-installing IIS

Everything has been working fine and I can't think of any configuration changes that would've stopped localhost from working. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Think yourself first.